# Laws on buying rifles in Turkey?

Tags: firearms, weapons

Are there any laws regarding the prohibition of selling rifles in Turkey? I have been going through the sites of various arms-dealers and all I can find is hunting-rifles, which take shells. What I am looking for are actual semi-automatic rifles. I'm going to live there in the future and am a gun-lover, and would love to own a couple. Anyone who lives there with experience or knowledge on this?

Answer (score 1):

Turkey does not allow civilian access to automatic or semi-automatic firearms. Sources differ in whether this is a total prohibition or that very few exceptions are allowed, but generally speaking you will not be allowed to have such a firearm.

Firearm ownership requires a license with mandatory background checks and demonstrating a "genuine reason". Collection is considered such a reason, but may involve more than just "I wanna".